# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded - set maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" updated but not working

Tags: wcf, binding, basichttpbinding, maxreceivedmessagesize

added maximum size on web config, but still showing the same error.

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcTYg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `maxReceivedMessageSize` both in your server-side and client-side. The code like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: downloading a CLOB file from oracle db. error occuring at that time.